# Laravel 5 Instantiate a new Request validattion

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to instantiate a new **Request** and not in the normal `public function store(Requests\CarRequest $request)` way.

I want to do it inside a loop to check multiple requests.

See code below:

```
$input = array(
    "car_1_car_to"       => "000",
    "car_1_arrival_time" => "2015/06/02 15:40",
    "car_1_leave_time"   => "2015/06/02 19:00"
);
$carRequest = new Requests\CarRequest($input);
```

How can I then get the status of the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking to run the validation here the best way would be to use the validator class directly. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation

```
// Array of validation rules
$rules = [
];

$input = [
    'car_1_car_to'       => '000',
    'car_1_arrival_time' => '2015/06/02 15:40',
    'car_1_leave_time'   => '2015/06/02 19:00',
];

$validator = \Validator::make($input, $rules);

if ($validator->fails())
{
    // Whoops, somethings wrong, do something.

    $errorMessages = $validator->messages();
}
```